# How can I create a semicircular button in JavaFx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I tried using methods suggested on [this link](http://pleasingsoftware.blogspot.in/2010/04/advanced-javafx-control-styling.html) but the semicircles just didn't look like a semicircle; Is there a better way?

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The link you provide is related to [obsolete JavaFX 1.x technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `-fx-shape` property of `Region` (see [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)) you can create a semicircular shaped `Button`.

```
button.setStyle(
        "-fx-shape:\"M0 0A1,1 0 0 0 2,0Z\";"

        // ensure x/y-scaling of shape will be 1:1
        + "-fx-min-height: 100;"
        + "-fx-min-width: 200;"
        + "-fx-max-height: 100;"
        + "-fx-max-width: 200;"
);
```